# javascript checking if file exists always catching error

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, bots

im having problems checking if a file exists for my shop system it will always catch the error as no shop in location when there is an existing file any help or idea's would be much appreciated.

```js
const fs = require('fs')
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { pagify } = require('../../Util/utils');

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
    let userDB = bot.db.get(message.author.id);
    let locationUser = userDB.location
    let locationShop = (`../../json/location/shop/${locationUser}.json`)


    try{
    fs.existsSync(locationShop);{

    
    let page = isNaN(args[0]) ? 1 : Number(args.shift())


        let sortiment = Object.entries(locationShop.shop).filter(i => !i[1].hidden)
        let items = pagify(sortiment, 10, page)

    message.channel.send(bot.embed(items.map(i => `**${i[0]}** - price: **$${i[1].price}** - description: ${i[1].description}`).join('\n')))

}}catch(e){
message.channel.send(`No shop in this location`)
}

}
```

Is there any other way to check if a file exists? I need the command to run if there is no file and provide a response instead of the command not working.

Comment: What is the actual exception that's thrown?

Comment: `fs.exists()` is deprecated. You should use `fs.stat()`

Comment: @nadz could you explain do you mean the catch(e) ?

Comment: @ViridianZe Yes, what is the exception (e).

Comment: @nadz it is meant to be if locationShop doesn't exist catch the error and say no shop found

Comment: If there's an error, it's always helpful to have it included in your question.

Comment: @Elitezen ive solved it dw

Answer (score 0):

fixed the code with Try and catch statements

```js
let locationShop;
        try {
            locationShop = require(`../../json/location/shop/${locationUser}.json`)
            let page = isNaN(args[0]) ? 1 : Number(args.shift())
            let sortiment = Object.entries(locationShop.shop).filter(i => !i[1].hidden)
            let items = pagify(sortiment, 10, page)


        message.channel.send(bot.embed(items.map(i => `**${i[0]}** - price: **$${i[1].price}** - description: ${i[1].description}`).join('\n')))
         console.log(`Shop Found at ${locationUser}`)
     } catch (e) {
         message.channel.send(bot.embed(`${locationUser} doesn't have a shop.`))
          console.log(`location file doesn't exist.`)
        }
```